# The subject in 洗車を終えた車をふたりがかりで拭いているのを見ながら

Tags: grammar, subjects

> 洗車を終えた車をふたりがかりで拭いているのを見ながら、喜一は、ああしていくうちに悦子の指のしもやけはまたもや悪化するのだろうな、などとぼんやり考えていた。

洗車を終えた means finished washing the car.
車をふたりがかりで拭いているの means two people wiping the car together.

1) But I would like to know whether the subject of 洗車を終えた is 喜一? So after 喜一 finished washing the car, he watched two people wiping the car together? If not, what is the subject of 洗車を終えた?

2) This sentence looks confusing to me as if 洗車を終えた is used to modify the 車 after it so it reads like "the car that has finished washing the car".  I would like to know what kind of sentence structure is this?  It seems that something is missing after 洗車を終えた.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Looking at this sentence alone, the people who washed the car are probably the same two people who are wiping the car now; one is 悦子, and the other is someone not directly mentioned in this sentence. 喜一 has been just looking.
2. 洗車を終えた車 is not "the car that has finished washing" but "the car *they* have finished washing". It's a noun phrase with a relative clause made from 車の洗車を終えた, although this seems a bit tautological :)